# dcolumn with brackets

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, dcolumn

I am using dcolumn to align cells to the decimal point. But in case of brackets, I always got overfull errors in my main document. If I replicate a MWE with the full preamble, there are no more overfull errors anymore (TexStudio), but the problem is still visible with `\overfullrule=1mm`

My question is the following:

Which is the best way to achieve alignment to the decimal point if values in brackets are included? Ideally, the vertical space between the columns would be even, as in the first example, but without the overfull space.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline, headings=small,]{scrreprt}
\overfullrule=1mm
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{N}{D..{2.2}} 
\newcolumntype{Z}{D..{1.2}} 

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[t]
\caption{caption x}
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{-1.5pt} % general space between cols (6pt standard)
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ZNNNNN}
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{1}{r}{Const term} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$xcvb^e$} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$xcvb$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$xcvb$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$xcvb$} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$xcvb$ add a} \\
\midrule 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$xcvb^e$} & 4.12 & 4.12 & 4.12 & -8.97 & -8.97 & -12.98 \\
& (3.54) & (1.95) & (0.64) & (-0.73) & (-1.57) & \\[6pt]
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$xcvb$} & 0.02 & -0.27 & 0.88 & -0.04 & 0.13 & -12.98 \\
& (3.35) & (-0.12) & (-0.12) & (-0.12) & (-0.12) & \\[6pt]
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$xcvb$} & 0.03 & 0.46 & -0.00 & 0.99 & -0.00 & -12.98 \\
& (1.35) & (22.38) & (22.38) & (22.38) & (22.38) & \\[6pt]
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$xcvb$} & 0.07 & -0.03 & -0.00 & 0.01 & 0.93 & -12.98 \\
& (2.63) & (-0.55) & (41.45) & (88.34) & (88.88) & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't look like a real MWE. Most of the loaded packages aren't needed to reproduce problem and I can't see the need for two example tables. More Details on a MWE here: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: @someonr I provided only parts of my preamble which I thought could be interesting to this question. How can I know in advance what causes the problem? I removed the second example though.

Comment: try to remove lines that won't effect the warning. I just tried that and got:
`\documentclass[draft]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{N}{D..{2.2}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{N}
 (3.54) \\
\end{tabular}



\end{document}` (format is ugly in the comments)

Comment: possible duplicate of [aligning numbers with brackets in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96003/aligning-numbers-with-brackets-in-tables)

Comment: @someonr I think eg `geometry` is important for overfull errors because it limits the available horizontal space. But nvm - if you believe something is absolutely not needed, I don't mind if you edit the post.

Comment: Just add one decimal point for the brackets like `\newcolumntype{N}{D..{2.3}} 
\newcolumntype{Z}{D..{1.3}}` and your problem will be gone ;) I think all relevant info is here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96003/aligning-numbers-with-brackets-in-tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just increase you decimal specifiers by `1` before and after the decimal to include an extra place for the bracket:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline, headings=small,]{scrreprt}
\overfullrule=1mm
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{N}{D..{3.3}} 
\newcolumntype{Z}{D..{2.3}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\caption{caption x}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ZNNNNN}
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{1}{r}{Const term} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$xcvb^e$} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$xcvb$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$xcvb$} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$xcvb$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$xcvb$ add a} \\
\midrule 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$xcvb^e$} & 4.12 & 4.12 & 4.12 & -8.97 & -8.97 & -12.98 \\
& (3.54) & (1.95) & (0.64) & (-0.73) & (-1.57) & \\[6pt]
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$xcvb$} & 0.02 & -0.27 & 0.88 & -0.04 & 0.13 & -12.98 \\
& (3.35) & (-0.12) & (-0.12) & (-0.12) & (-0.12) & \\[6pt]
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$xcvb$} & 0.03 & 0.46 & -0.00 & 0.99 & -0.00 & -12.98 \\
& (1.35) & (22.38) & (22.38) & (22.38) & (22.38) & \\[6pt]
\multicolumn{1}{l}{$xcvb$} & 0.07 & -0.03 & -0.00 & 0.01 & 0.93 & -12.98 \\
& (2.63) & (-0.55) & (41.45) & (88.34) & (88.88) & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```